# How to avoid re-rendering when changing an element depth in the Node Tree?

Tags: reactjs

For example:

```
Element A
   Element B
Element C
```

If I move Element B and posit it as the next sibling of C:

```
Element A
Element C
Element B
```

sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-butterfly-g5rei?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Is it possible to avoid re-rendering Element B?

All 3 elements are memo-ed and have unique ids as their keys.
But React still re-render B. In fact React recreated it.

Comment: It's vague to identify why your component re-renders, could you give an reproducible example using Codesandbox?

Comment: @dongnhan Thanks, added a simplified example.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children - your question explained.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial  I see... The keys only works among siblings. It won't work if I move the element to other subtrees. Thanks...

Comment: just follow the rules, and let react do it's job. :). Code first, optimise later.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial ww.. yeah. But my goal is to keep B focused before and after moving..... now I have to manually focus it again and posit the caret correctly...T-T